# ¿Como soluciono este error en un comando SQL Server para copiar filas de una tabla en filas de otra tabla de otra base?

Tags: sql-server

El comando que uso es:

INSERT INTO [Base1].dbo.Tabla1 SELECT * FROM [Base2].dbo.Tabla2

Ambas bases tienen idéntica estructura.
Tabla1 y Tabla2 tienen definido un índice único (al costado aparece con un símbolo de llave):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando ejecuto el comando anterior me sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

Mens. 8101, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 1
Solo puede especificarse un valor explícito para la columna de identidad de la tabla 'Base1.dbo.Tabla1' cuando se usa una lista de columnas e IDENTITY_INSERT es ON.

¿Cómo hago para copiar todas las filas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que habilites la insersion de identidad de esta forma luego realiza el insert y luego la vuelves deshabilitar.

Aquí el código SQL:

Habilita el insert

```sql
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Base1].dbo.Tabla1 ON;
```

Haz la inserción:

```sql
INSERT INTO [Base1].dbo.Tabla1 SELECT * FROM [Base2].dbo.Tabla2;
```

... y luego habilitar nuevamente la restricción de identidad

```sql
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Base1].dbo.Tabla1 OFF;
```